# How to hide the Show Applications button in Dash to Panel

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I am using Arc Menu on Dash to Panel and the *Show applications* button is sitting there doing nothing. Since it is wasting space, I want to remove it.

[image: Desktop with Dash to Panel]

I have tried almost everything, like hiding it from Dash to Dock, but with Dash to Panel it's not working.

Here is the way I found how to remove it with Dash to Dock:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-show-apps-button false
```

I changed the above command as follows to make it work with Dash to Panel:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-panel show-show-apps-button false
```

But it still doesn't work.

Please tell me how to hide that *Show Applications* button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>right-click</kbd> on the Dash to Panel dock → *Dash to Panel Settings* and in the *Position* tab click the <kbd>Visible</kbd> button next to the *Show Applications button* entry.

[image: Dash to Panel Settings]